# I don't know how to make a new matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib, plot, ipython, interactive, jupyter

[image]I'm using Jupyter notebook with  **%matplotlib notebook** in one of the first lines.

When making multiple plots, I have to physically press the 'stop interaction' button on each figure before running another plot, or else the newest plot will be overlaid onto the previous figure.

I think the problem is that I'm not specifying that a new figure needs to be made for each plot? But I'm stumped as to how best to do that!

DO I REALLY HAVE TO SAY PLT.FIGURE EVERY SINGLE TIME? THIS SEEMS UNLIKELY TO ME...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you mean `%matplotlib notebook`?  When you want a new figure, make a new figure via `plt.figure()`.  The ability to add/remove lines from an existing plot is one of the key features of the notebook backend and brings it to parity with the rest of the interactive backends.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I meant **%matplotlib notebook** I can add figures easily, but in jupyter I have to stop interactions in order to make a new figure, otherwise the plot is put overlaid on the already open figure. I don't like having to always press the 'stop interactions' button on every figure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with the notebook backend, but luckily the person who reported it also reported [a workaround](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6071)

Answer (score 4):

Within the Notebook you will need to add the plt.ioff after you import pyplot.

Here is a snip from the top of a notebook, that makes it work for me. I was getting plots over written like you.

```
%matplotlib notebook   # this is to allow the plotting in the notebook

import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import hadamard
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ioff()    # this stops the graphs from overwriting each other
```